# Error in writing a function in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm working with cakephp for project development. I wrote a function to get data from the database and do a summation.I have created a table called user with height and weight in it. I want to retrieve that data,add them, and to return that. Here is the function I wrote.

```
public function calculate()
{
    $Height=$this->set('user',$this->User->find('first'));
    $Weight=$this->set('user1',$this->User->find('first'));
    $sum=($Height+$Weight);
    $this->set('SUM',$sum);
}
```

In the view I wrote the following code.

```
<div class="page-content">
<?php echo $user['User']['weight']; ?>
<?php echo $user1['User']['height']; ?>
<?php echo $SUM ?>
</div
```

Height and weight values are getting displayed. But the sum value is displayed as zero. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: check your variable height and weight in controller , they are not height and weight from user model/table , the one you are showing in your view.

Comment: try to convert it height and weight variable to int before calculating the sum

Comment: The `set()` method is meant to send data to the view and so it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to do the above calculation. I used the following code in the controller.

```
public function calculate($id=null)
    {
        if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        $this->set('user1',$this->User->find('first', array('fields' => ('height'),'conditions' => array('User.id' =>$id))));
        $this->set('user',$this->User->find('first', array('fields' => ('weight'),'conditions' => array('User.id' =>$id))));
    }
```

My view looks similar to the one mentioned above. This works fine with me...

Comment: You don't have to use `find()` twice, simply use an array with "height" and "width" as elements for the "fields" option.

Comment: as dhofset pointed, you can add both the fields in single array.So no need to fire the find query twice.It should be like,

$this->set('user',$this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$id),'fields'=>array('height','weight'))));

Answer (score 0):

First you need get the field from find. (You can use find condition to filter de user id for example).

```
 $user = $this->User->find('first', array(
     'conditions' => array('User.id' => $id),
     'fields' => array('User.height', 'User.weight') // fields from your DB
));
```

So, you can do a `pr($user)` to see the data and know what use.

After do the sum and set to the view. [Cakephp Set](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::set)

Comment: @Roshani the way to say thanks here is to upvote or accept the answer. If you think your answer is better (even though this is better perfomance-wise and it probably led you to your solution), then mark yours, but either way, mark one.